# Magento 2.1.5 Theme not loading correctly (worked perfect in 2.1.2)

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, xml, head

We have updated our magento 2 installation from 2.1.2 to 2.1.5.
Everything went fine, except for the layout.

Somehow Magento doesn't load some parts of our custom theme anymore? For example the file:
**app/design/frontend/Wantsandneeds/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

Is not triggered anymore? It worked well in 2.1.2
What has changed regarding to themes?

Answer (score 2):

Check what type id your theme has in the database, (theme table). apparently there is something called virtual themes that can cause issues like the one you describe. "Standard" themes have type 0, virtual 1. More on that here: [Magento 2 - Theme Type 0:physical, 1:virtual, 2:staging. When to use?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92181/magento-2-theme-type-0physical-1virtual-2staging-when-to-use)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. but all the themes have type 0. So that's not our solution.

Comment: If your theme files disappear (for example if you move the folder or switch to a git branch which doesn't have the theme), then Magento will change the theme to virtual (1).  Restore the theme files, then ```update theme set type = 0 where theme_id = <your theme ID>```