# I can overwrite a layout in my parent theme, but not in my child theme. What is wrong with this?

Tags: magento-2.1, layout

I am fairly new to Magento and I am currently working with version 2.1. I have created two new custom themes, I will call them Base and BaseChild for this example.

```
Locations
app/design/frontend/Base/default        //Inherits from Luma
app/design/frontend/BaseChild/default   //Inherites from Base
```

Inside the admin area, I have the base website set to use the BaseChild theme, and I have another site setup that is also using the BaseChild theme.

If I create a template file at `BaseChild/default/Magento_Theme/templates/html/absolute_footer.phtml` and add content to it, this will override the section on the page properly for the template. However, if I create a layout file at `BaseChild/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` and add the following content to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

This does nothing. But if I put this same file in the parent at `Base/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` it works and the footer is gone.

Why is my child theme not overriding properly even though the parent theme is.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I realize I'm years late to the question, but I struggled to find this answer for hours. Hopefully this will help someone else. This worked in Magento 2.4 on my child theme. Not sure if changing a child theme type will have any bad affects as updates come out.

> Go to your database. select **theme** table. Check custom theme record. If the value of the type field is 1 change it to 0. This fixed my issue.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7710#issuecomment-306389802

After finding this answer I was able to find this question with an answer that gives a little more insight.

[Magento 2 - Theme Type 0:physical, 1:virtual, 2:staging. When to use?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92181/magento-2-theme-type-0physical-1virtual-2staging-when-to-use)

Comment: I was stuck and notice your post and it works for me, you are awesome DiddleDot.

Answer (score 0):

You should place you override file into `BaseChild/Magento_Theme/layout/override/theme/Magento/Base/default.xml`

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html#theme-inherit-layout-over

Comment: I tried this as well, which was not working. This would override the layout though, and I am trying to extend it in my example.

Comment: Though, getting either to work would be a start.

Comment: My reference contains info for extending layout

Comment: Yeah, thats the exact same tutorial I used to get to where I am. The problem is, it only deals with one theme deep inheritance.

Comment: Then it's strange. Did you set parent on `theme.xml`?

Comment: Yes. I have the Base theme parent set to `Magento/luma`, and the BaseChild theme parent set to `Base/default`. Really though, the templates would not be working if this was not setup properly (but they are working). It is the layout in the BaseChild that is not working though.

Comment: Maybe other 3rd party modules/themes also overriding this layout, you should have code check.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a `Vendor` name and move your themes inside the `Vendor` folder. Your folder structure would look like this:

```
app/design/frontend/
├── <Vendor>/
│   │   ├──base/
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   ├──baseChild/
│   │   │   ├── ...
│   │   │   ├── ...
```

Then change the `<parent>` tag of your baseChild's `theme.xml` to

```
<parent>Vendor/base</parent>
```

And finally, move your theme files out of the `default` folder and put them directly under the theme folder, e.g. the path of your baseChild's layout file should now become:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/baseChild/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Visit the [official documentation page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) for further information.

Comment: Sorry I am already doing this. I just expected that it was implied to be in the correct spot, and I put the wrong directory structure. I am fixing that now. Vendor in your example would be Base/BaseChild in mine. And baseChild would be default. The base is inheriting correctly, and in the BaseChild I can override templates just fine so I know thats inheriting correctly. It is the layouts that are not.