# CSS are compiled but not called in frontend

Tags: magento2, css, frontend, cache, less

I added css on my website. One is bootstrap and one is a custom css.
I addedd it on my Magento_Theme folder (inside `layout/default_head_block.xml`)

```
<css src="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" order="100" />
<css src="css/reflexmania2-custom.css" order="100" />
```

suddenly there was a problem on these css. They are not loaded in the frontend css inside the HEAD tag.

i tried cleaning cache, generated folders, view_preprocessed and then running

```
setup:upgrade
setup:di:compile
setup:static-content:deploy
```

but nothing. they are not loaded.

they are compiled because i can see inside my pub/static folder.

i'm getting crazy. How can i solve this problem?

Thanks for help

EDIT: 1 --> added xml default_head_blocks.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

 <css src="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" order="100" />
 <css src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css"  src_type="url" order="100" />
 <css src="css/reflexmania2-custom.css" order="100" />

</head>
</page>
```

Some notes: inside my Pub/static folder i have got all my css and layout.they are not working nor called from my theme. If i restore a previous version of my theme is the same. I think that there is some problem on pub static or some permission but i cannot understand where.

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TDjf.png)

Comment: Can you specify your CSS file path? Also please make sure that layout file name should be `default_head_blocks.xml`

Comment: yes, i put css inside Theme/Module/web/css folder. I see that there is some xml errors because the theme is not loaded properly and my changes to the XML are not loaded properly. How can i debug the error?

Comment: Is your XML file name with `blocks` ? In your question, you mentioned block

Comment: yes. the name is correct

Comment: Can you add the code of your entire XML file?

Comment: added the xml. i don't understand where i can manage to solve it. And the terrible is that i cannot understand how to debug it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87960/discussion-between-francesco-and-abhishek-panchal).

Comment: lets discuss in chat

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no `order` property, with this you should have an Exception (property not valid).

To add css :

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <css src="css/reflexmania2-custom.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/css/bootstrap.css

```
/*Some content*/
```

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/css/reflexmania2-custom.css

```
/*Some content*/
```

Then execute : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: no. nothing solved. i tried switching databases with one website that it's working and this solved the problem. i think there is something inside the database or inside the pub static folder that it's not loaded properlu

Comment: maybe there is some problem on the pub static folder or some htaccess...

Answer (score 0):

solved this problem.
I don't know how but something changed my theme from phisical to virtual on my db table 'themes'.
Just changed the value from 0 -> 1 and all works without problems.

this looks like a problem of magento2 and virtual themes is not completely developed:
[Magento 2 - Theme Type 0:physical, 1:virtual, 2:staging. When to use?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92181/magento-2-theme-type-0physical-1virtual-2staging-when-to-use)