# Magneto 2 virtual theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

Some please explain me what is virtual theme in Magento.
How can I create and implement on frontend?

Is this only available for Magento enterprise edition?

Comment: duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92181/magento-2-theme-type-0physical-1virtual-2staging-when-to-use ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2 - Theme Type 0:physical, 1:virtual, 2:staging. When to use?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92181/magento-2-theme-type-0physical-1virtual-2staging-when-to-use)